# Extending continuous function $D\to I$, where $D$ is a dense subspace of a separable Tychonoff space

Tags: gn.general-topology, soft-question

Suppose the countable subspace $D$ is dense in the separable Tychonoff space $X$ and $f$ is a continuous function from $D$ to the closed unit interval. What are some conditions on $X$ or $D$, which make $f$ continuously extendable over $X$？

Comment: Are you aware of Tietze's Extension Theorem? It's related, but with a $T_4$ space $X$ rather than $T_{3.5}$. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem

Comment: But here $D$ is dense, so Tietze applies only if $D=X$...

Answer (score 6):

A relevant paper is

Taĭmanov, A. D.
[On extension of continuous mappings of topological spaces](http://mi.mathnet.ru/msb5540). (Russian)
Mat. Sbornik N.S. 31(73), (1952). 459–463.
56.0X

The [MR of this paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0050871) is:

Let $S$ be a $T_1$-space, $A$ a dense subspace of $S$, and $R$ a compact Hausdorff space. Let $f$ be a continuous mapping of $A$ into $R$. Then $f$ admits a continuous extension over $S$ if and only if for all disjoint closed subsets $A_1,A_2$ of $R$, the relation $(f^{-1}(A_1))^-\cap(f^{-1}(A_2))^-=0$ obtains (closure in $S$). From this result, a theorem of Yu. M. Smirnov [Uspehi Matem. Nauk 6, no. 4(44), 204--206 (1951)] is easily proved, as well as a theorem of Vulih [Mat. Sbornik N.S. 30(72), 167--170 (1952); [MR0048790](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0048790) (14,70c)]. A final corollary is a special case of a theorem widely known and recently published by Katětov [Fund. Math. 38, 85--91 (1951); [MR0050264](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0050264) (14,304a)].

I remembered this because as a graduate student I used it to give a (I think new at the time) proof that every compact Hausdorff space is a continuous image of a compact totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space (which, in turn, I use these days to reduce proving  the Riesz representation theorem for $C(K)$ to the case where the compact space $K$ is totally disconnected).

Answer (score 5):

The criterion for "EVERY continuous map from $D$ to $[0, 1]$ has a continuous extension to $X$" is that any two disjoint zerosets in $D$ have disjoint closures in $X$. You can find this in Chapter 6 of Gillman and Jerison's classic "Rings of Continuous Functions".  They also consider the "local problem" of continuously extending a single map at length in some of the exercises, e.g. given $f:D\rightarrow Y$ (not necessarily $Y=[0, 1]$) Exercise 6G characterizes the largest subspace of $X$ to which $f$ can be continuously extended in terms of $z$-filters.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I can't find the book of "Rings of Continuous Functions". Could you tell me where i can find this book?

Comment: You'll probably have to go through some sort of interlibrary loan, although Amazon lists some used copies available for purchase.

Comment: @Paul I just found [it at Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=3j3SBwAAQBAJ).

Answer (score 4):

The situation is analogous to the particular case of $X$ a metric space, for any Tychonoff space $X$ is [uniformisable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformisable), and a real valued function $f$ on a dense subset $D$ of a uniform space $X$ is certainly continuously extendable to $X$ provided it is uniformly continuous. This is also a necessary condition if $X$ is compact, for any continuous function on a compact uniform space is always uniformly continuous.

Comment: Is "Any Tychonoff space X is uniformisable" means that every Tychonoff space is a uniform space?

Comment: Pietro provided a link to Wikipedia in his answer. But the answer is essentially yes; the topology on $X$ will be compatible with a construction that makes $X$ into a uniform space.

Comment: Yes, it admits a uniform structure (not unique in general). So the complete answer is: $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$ wrto one such uniform structures. 

Comment: To be specific, $f$ is extendable if and only if it is uniformly continuous wrt (the restriction to $D$ of) the fine uniformity on $X$.

Comment: Sorry, what does "wrt" mean?

Comment: With respect to

Answer (score 3):

At least in the case of a metric space $X$, such a function $f$ extends from $D$ to all of $X$ if and only if $f$ maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences (note that this is a weaker condition than uniform continuity).

As mentioned by Pietro, for your general Tychonoff space $X$, you make it a uniform space, so I think you can generalize my statement above to the following: $f$ extends if and only if $f$ maps Cauchy nets to Cauchy nets.

Comment: Also note that a function maps Cauchy nets to Cauchy nets if and only if it is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Pietro: Are you sure? For example, every continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to any uniform space also maps Cauchy nets to Cauchy nets. (Let `$\{x_a\}_{a\in D}$` be a Cauchy net. There is $a_0$ such that $|x_a-x_{a_0}|\le1$ for every $a\ge a_0$, hence all such $x_a$ are confined to the compact interval $I=[x_{a_0}-1,x_{a_0}+1]$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $I$, which implies that `$\{f(x_a)\}_{a\in D}$` is Cauchy.)

Comment: OTOH, Christopher’s condition is clearly not necessary, even in the metric case. For instance, if $D=X$, then every continuous $f$ trivially extends, but in general does not map Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences (e.g., take $X=\mathbb Q$, $f(x)=0$ for $x<\pi$, $f(x)=1$ for $x>\pi$).

Comment: @Emil: oh yes, my distraction!


Comment: @ Emil: In the metric case, I suppose I was thinking of the process of completion as uniquely determined by Cauchy sequences. So perhaps what I really want is that $f$ maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences, wherever these Cauchy sequences converge to a point $p \notin D$, $p \in X$.

Answer (score 1):

Several years ago I encountered a similar problem in my joint investigation with Misha Mitrofanov and I solved it as follows (see our paper “[Approximation of continuous functions on Fréchet spaces](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.1814)” (English version is downloadable in the source file)).

We say that a filter $\mathcal F$ on a topological space is *convergent*, if a set of limits of $\mathcal F$ is non-empty.

Let $X$  be a topological space, $Y$ be a regular topological space, $D$  be a dense subset of the space $X$,  $g : D\to Y$  be a map, and let  $\mathcal  F$ be a filter on the space  $X$.  Let  $g(F)$ be a filter on the space  $Y$  generated by the base $\{g(F): F\in \mathcal F\}$.  For every point  $x\in X$,  let $\mathcal F_x$ be the trace of the filter of all neighborhoods of the point $x$ on the set $D$.

**Lemma 1.**  A continuous map $f : D\to Y$ can be extended to a continuous map
 $\tilde f : X\to Y$ iff for any point  $x\in X$ the filter $f(\mathcal F_x)$  is convergent.

We can simplify this condition when $X$ is a Fréchet–Urysohn space. That is if for any $A\subset X $ and any points $x\in\overline{A}$ there exists a sequence of points of the set $A$  convergent to  $x$.  In particular, every first countable space (and, hence, every metrizable space) is a Fréchet–Urysohn space.

**Lemma 2.**  Let  $X$   be a Fréchet-Urysohn topological space, $Y$  be a regular topological space, and $D$  be a dense subset of the space $X$.  A continuous mapping   $f : D\to Y$  can be extended to a continuous mapping $\hat f : X\to Y$ iff for each sequence $\{x_n\}$ of points of the set $D$ convergent in $X$, a sequence  $\{ f(x_n)\}$ is also convergent.